# MySQL Error 1064 (42000) when running UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this MySQL query?

**Query:**

```
UPDATE MATERIAL_MASTER SET MST_NAME='XXX' MAT_DESC='YYY' MAT_TYPE='Raw Material' MAT_GRP='H' UOM='kg' CURRENCY='inr' ENTITY_ASSEMBLED='A' where idMATERIAL_MASTER=3;
```

**Error:**

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAT_DESC='YYY' MAT_TYPE='Raw Material' MAT_GRP='H' UOM='kg' CURRENCY='inr' ENTIT' at line 1

Comment: YOU'RE MISSING COMMAS BETWEEN YOUR COLUMN IDENTIFIERS

Comment: 2014. years AD, we have people able to connect to internet, yet unable to respect a simple rule of DO NOT USE CAPS LOCK WHILE ASKING PEOPLE FOR HELP BECAUSE IT'S DUMB AND YOU DIDN'T LEARN THAT AT SCHOOL.

Comment: PLEASE TRY TO MAKE UR KNOWLEDGE VALUABLE IN SOME OTHER PLACE..THIS IS NOT THE PROPER PLACE FOR YOU...  @N.B.:-this comment is for those DUMB people who thinks that they are very smart....HEHE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this:

```
UPDATE MATERIAL_MASTER 
SET MST_NAME='XXX' MAT_DESC='YYY' 
MAT_TYPE='Raw Material' 
MAT_GRP='H' UOM='kg' CURRENCY='inr'
ENTITY_ASSEMBLED='A'
where idMATERIAL_MASTER=3;
```

You're missing commas between fields in SET zone.

The correct query is:

```
UPDATE MATERIAL_MASTER 
SET MST_NAME='XXX', MAT_DESC='YYY', 
MAT_TYPE='Raw Material', 
MAT_GRP='H', UOM='kg', CURRENCY='inr',
ENTITY_ASSEMBLED='A'
where idMATERIAL_MASTER=3;
```